# Postgres SQL query with CTE and temporary column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to make the following query working:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT org_uid, uid, category, severity, source, created_at, 
  updated_at, delivery_date, finding_id, client_id, client_note, 
  definition, recommendations, details, resources, tags, text, type, sub_category, 
  (SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM MAX(fs.remediated_at) - findings.created_at) AS INTEGER) FROM "public"."findings-subjects" fs WHERE fs.finding_uid = findings.uid) AS time_to_remediate 
  FROM "public"."findings" 
  WHERE org_uid = '127cb14a-bbbb-dddd-aaaa-451e7cea3f94'
) SELECT org_uid, uid, category, severity, source, created_at, updated_at, delivery_date, 
finding_id, client_id, client_note, definition, recommendations, details, 
resources, tags, text, type, sub_category, time_to_remediate 
WHERE time_to_remediate BETWEEN 3 AND 7 
LIMIT 1000 
OFFSET 0
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error saying `ERROR:  column "org_uid" does not exist at character 491`
I'm not sure where's the bug in the query. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main query does not contain the `FROM`clause.

Add `FROM cte` before the third last line;)

Comment: That was it! I was struggling to notice it for hours!